# Using Doctrine inside ZF2 Models

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I'm working for the first time to get Doctrine working with a new ZF2 app.  Doctrine is working fine if I call it within the controller (like every last tutorial out there has you do), however it doesn't make any sense performing business logic in the controller.

A few things I found suggests dependency injection passing the Entity Manager in from the controller, some suggest having your class implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface.

My question is, how is anyone else using it within their models?  Surely someone is using it the correct (MVC) way and not putting all of their business logic within their application controllers?

Answer (score 1):

There are of course different solutions for this, but I personally use a Service layer. So for instance you would have a UserService which takes care of handling the business logic of User objects.

To allow the service to do its job you would inject its dependencies. Implementing ServiceLocatorAwareInterface is an option, but if you find yourself using getServiceLocator()->get('...') a lot it becomes a pita to write unit tests and injecting mock objects. A hybrid solution for that would be to have your service implement ServiceLocatorAwareInterface and have a getServiceA() and setServiceA() method where the getServiceA would look like:

```
if (!$this->serviceA)
{
    $this->getServiceLocator()->get('ServiceA');
}

return $this->serviceA;
```

That way you can still inject a mock version of the dependency in your unit test.

Answer (score 1):

I usually make a Service and instantiate it with a Factory in which I inject either the `ServiceLocator` or the `EntityManager` itself directly into the service. The typical folder structure would look something like

```
\src
   \Module
       \Controller
       \Service
           BusinessService.php
       \Factory
           BusinessServiceFactory.php
```

In your `Module.php` or the equivalent in `module.config.php` for that matter

```
function getServiceConfig() {
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            'service.business' => 'Module\src\Module\Factory\BusinessServiceFactory,
        ),
    )
}
```

Then the actual Service and the Factory itself

### BusinessServiceFactory.php

```
namespace Module\Factory\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class BusinessServiceFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function createService(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $service = new BusinessService($serviceLocator);

        return $service;
    }
}
```

### BusinessService.php

```
namespace Module\Service;

use Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceLocatorInterface;

class BusinessService
{
    /**
     * @var Service locator
     */
    protected $serviceLocator;

    public function __construct(ServiceLocatorInterface $serviceLocator)
    {
        $this->serviceLocator = $serviceLocator;
    }
}
```

You can now define all your business logic in the `BusinessService` class. It is callable from your Controllers by `this->serviceLocator->get('service.business')`